# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.4:repackaged (repackage) on project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

While compiling a maven project I get the error after running mvn clean, then mvn install.

> Error - Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.4:repackage (repackage) on project project name.

I tried to add this in my pom.xml but still doesn't works:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <group ID>org.springframework.boot</group ID>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7.4</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <goals>
    <goal>repackage</goal>
    </goals>
   </execution> 
</executions> 
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

Have tried rebuilding the project, doing mvn clean then mvn install but this does not work.
What should I do to get rid of error?

Comment: Please post the full output of the error... and not excerpts.... otherwise we can not even guess...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.